# golang sftp This service allows sftp connections only

Tags: go, sftp

```
func (c *Client) Upload(local, remote string) error {
    client, err := sftp.NewClient(c.SSHClient)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()
    localFile, err := os.Open(local)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer localFile.Close()
    remoteFile, err := client.Create(remote)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(remoteFile, localFile)
    return err
}
```

I call this function to upload a file to SFTP without any return error.

Use the command line to upload as follows:
[Command execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nZOY.jpg)

I am operating this function

```
var localFilePath = "./1234.zip"
var remoteDir = "upload/uuuuu.zip"
err = client.Upload(localFilePath, remoteDir)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("ok")
```

Execution result returns no error, only returns: Upload file completed

But landing SFTP, there is no upload file, ask everyone to point!
Introduced:
This service allows sftp connections only
go version go1.10.2 linux/amd64

Simplify the code, the whole process is like this

```
func Consftp(username, host, privKeyPath, local, remote string) error {
    privKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privKeyPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(privKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    authMethod := ssh.PublicKeys(signer)
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            username,
        Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{authMethod},
        HostKeyCallback: HostKeyCallback,
    }

    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host, config)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    client, err := sftp.NewClient(conn)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()
    localFile, err := os.Open(local)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer localFile.Close()
    remoteFile, err := client.Create(remote)
    println(err)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(remoteFile, localFile)
    return err
}
```

code full

```
package until

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "github.com/pkg/sftp"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)
func Consftp(username, host, privKeyPath, local, remote string) error {
    privKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privKeyPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(privKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    authMethod := ssh.PublicKeys(signer)
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            username,
        Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{authMethod},
        HostKeyCallback: HostKeyCallback,
    }

    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host, config)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    client, err := sftp.NewClient(conn)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()
    localFile, err := os.Open(local)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer localFile.Close()
    remoteFile, err := client.Create(remote)
    println(err)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(remoteFile, localFile)
    return err
}
```

Comment: You say your code is returning no error? How are you getting the message "This service allows sftp connections only"? Is this message coming from your program? What part of the program is printing this message?

Comment: This is not a code return. It is a SSH login that is not configured by the server.

Comment: @medtrib, you're not closing the remote file before closing the connection.

Comment: The link is not closed. You mean that SSH is not closed, but why upload files without uploading files, without any error.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you're closing the _client_ without closing the file. I'd have to look into whatever sftp package you're using, but most file-like interfaces require closing the descriptor to ensure that the data pas been persisted. There's no case where closing the client before the file makes any sense, so you should fix that first and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: `package until

import (
 "io"
 "io/ioutil"
 "os"

 "github.com/pkg/sftp"
 "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)`

Comment: Your question has been updated and the code has been edited. Please have a look.